# Create Makefile to be used in different environments for C++

Tags: c++, makefile

I would like to compile and run my program in two different environments. The libraries in both environments are installed on slightly different places, resulting in different makefile-lines:
In makefile A:

```
CXXFLAGS=-I$(DIR) -flto -fopenmp -O3 -g -march=native -std=gnu++17 -c -I/opt/interp2d/include -std=c++17 -I/opt/splinter/include -I/usr/include/eigen3
```

In makefile B:

```
CXXFLAGS=-I$(DIR) -nostindc++ -I~/local_opt/eigen/include/eigen3/ -I~/local_opt/boost/include -I~/local_opt/armadillo/include -flto -fopenmp -O3 -g -march=native -std=gnu++17 -c -I~/local_opt/interp2d/include -std=c++17 -I~/local_opt/splinterp/include -I/usr/include/eigen3
```

My problem now is that I am developing the program on the first machine, using makefile A, but also deploying it on the second machine. The deployment is done using `git`.
Every time I do a `git pull` on the second machine, I have to fix all the paths in the makefile in order to compile the program properly. Nevertheless I still would like to include the makefile in the git repository in order to keep both makefiles at the same level regarding compiling flags and linked libraries.
Thus, is there an easier way to still sync the makefile via `git`, while using different paths for the libraries and includes?

Comment: I am not sure if this is something that you are looking for, but you can make a script(shell, python) that automatically detects, and updates the paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could solve your problem by [conditionally](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Syntax.html) setting the variable `CXXFLAGS` in a common file (e.g.: `config.mk`) and by [including](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Include.html) that file in your makefiles.

The value used for setting the `CXXFLAGS` variable could, for example, depend on the value of the environment variable `HOST`:

```
ifeq ($(HOST),A)
   CXXFLAGS = ... # for machine A
else # B
   CXXFLAGS = ... # for machine B
endif
```

Then, include this `config.mk` makefile in both `makefileA` and `makefileB`:

```
include config.mk
```

Comment: Actually, you don't even need to do the include -- you could just inline this code in your main makefile.

Answer (score 2):

I like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49007244/8012646), however, I thought I'd mention this for completeness:  If you have a lot of different hosts you can do something to the effect of:

```
include HostConfig_$(HOST).mk
```

And then create `HostConfig_A.mk` and `HostConfig_B.mk` which set host specific flags (Be it directories, etc).   This is useful if you are managing a large project with lots of different host-specific variables.

As well, (for smaller projects), you could do something to the effect of:

```
CXX_INCLUDES_A = ...
CXX_INCLUDES_B = ...

CXX_FLAGS := -I$(DIR) -flto -fopenmp -O3 -g -march=native -std=gnu++17
CXX_FLAGS += $(CXX_INCLUDES_$(HOST))
```

Answer (score 1):

The traditional answer to this problem is a configure script (see automake, autoconf for widely used framework). After checking out the source you run ./configure --with-eigen=~/local_opt/eigen/include/eigen3/ and it will adjust your Makefiles accordingly (usually generates Makefile from Makefile.in and only Makefile.in is in git).

Note: Properly done you only need to run configure on the first checkout, not on updates. make can generate Makefile again automatially as needed.

Comment: Another alternative would be CMake?

Comment: I do not have a problem with switching to CMake, after I am using it in another project already. The other alternatives are slightly more difficult  for me (configure, QMake)